# deploy app on to android with titanium

Tags: titanium

I havejust started having a play with Titanium to build a few small apps.

I have used one of the examples you can download and works fine on the mobile web preview.

I have connected my Samsung S3 and have tried deploying it to the that.

I get the following errors:

```
[TRACE] Writing out AndroidManifest.xml
[ERROR] Exception occured while building Android project:
[ERROR] Traceback (most recent call last):
[ERROR]   File "C:\Users\danyob\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.1.0.GA\android\builder.py", line 2553, in <module>
[ERROR]     builder.build_and_run(True, avd_id, device_args=device_args, debugger_host=debugger_host, profiler_host=profiler_host)
[ERROR]   File "C:\Users\danyob\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.1.0.GA\android\builder.py", line 2264, in build_and_run
[ERROR]     self.manifest_changed = self.generate_android_manifest(compiler)
[ERROR]   File "C:\Users\danyob\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.1.0.GA\android\builder.py", line 1404, in generate_android_manifest
[ERROR]     '-I', self.android_jar], warning_regex=r'skipping')
[ERROR]   File "C:\Users\danyob\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.1.0.GA\android\run.py", line 38, in run
[ERROR]     print "[DEBUG] %s" % subprocess.list2cmdline(args_to_log)
[ERROR]   File "C:\Users\danyob\AppData\Local\Titanium Studio\plugins\com.appcelerator.titanium.python.win32_1.0.0.1338515509\python\lib\subprocess.py", line 580, in list2cmdline
[ERROR]     needquote = (" " in arg) or ("\t" in arg) or not arg
[ERROR] TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
[ERROR] :  Build process exited with code 1
[ERROR] :  Project failed to build after 792ms
```

Anybody able to help?

As mentioned above this is an example app from titanium. It's the Geocoder one..

Cheers,
Dan

Comment: Can you build it and run it in the Android emulator?

Comment: @Martin, yes all works fine in the emulator

Comment: See if you can install the apk file from the build folder rather than using the automated deployment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'NoneType' is not iterable is a recent problem with Android updating thier SDK and it takes a little time for Appcelerator to release an SDK update of their own to accommodate.
here is more info:
http://developer.appcelerator.com/blog/2013/05/updating-to-android-r22-tools.html

others have solved it by creating sym links to the moved files: https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/152497/titanium-sdk-310-error-typeerror-argument-of-type-nonetype-is-not-iterable-on-building-android-app